# $Window.location.reload() FUNCTION

Tags: javascript, angularjs

II have implemented a map where it shows clients from a marker. The map I'm using is [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) with a [directive](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive) for AngularJS.

My problem is this, when I first access the map, it works normally, when I change the route, it erases all the markers, returning the map screen, it loads without the markers and they are shown only when I reload the page.

**$Window.location.reload() function.**

So I had the idea of ​​using $ window.location.reload () when I access the page where the map is located. I call the function when I click the menu icon (shortcut) of the page referring to the map and the page is reloaded showing the markers again.

```
vm.recarregarRota = function (){
    $window.location.reload();
}
```

**View:** This is the code that loads the map.

```
<div class="col-md-12 box_map" style="padding: 20px 30px 20px 30px;">
<div id="recent_activity" class="box_whiteframe_map">
    <leaflet defaults="vm.defaults" lf-center="vm.center" ng-init="vm.buscaEnderecoClientesEmpresas()" markers="vm.markers" width="100%" height="480px"></leaflet>
</div>
```

**Controller:** In the controller is the function used to load the DB data and assign it to the markers. It is also in this function that I create the markers. And extend the properties of the map, like telling it that its starting position is in such a coordinate ..

```
            vm.markers = new Array(); //CRIA MARKERS A SEREM UTILIZADOS NO MAP

    vm.buscaEnderecoClientesEmpresas = function() { //Function used to load DB data and assign to bookmarks. It is also in this function that I create the bookmarks ....

        vm.items.then(function(items) { // Read array of return
            relatoriosService.carregarEnderecoClientesEmpresas(dados).then(function(response) {
                if (response.data != 'null') {
                    vm.enderecoClientesEmpresas = response.data; //return array
                    angular.forEach(vm.enderecoClientesEmpresas, function(value, key) { //FOREACH UTILIZADO PARA PERCORRER ARRAY

                        vm.markers.push({
                            group: value.estado, //DATA FROM THE BD.
                            lat: value.latitude, //DATA FROM THE BD.
                            lng: value.longitude, //DATA FROM THE BD.
                            message: "teste",
                            icon: {
                                type: 'awesomeMarker',
                                prefix: 'fa',
                                icon: icon,
                                markerColor: color
                            },
                            label: {
                                options: {
                                    noHide: true
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    vm.enderecoClientesEmpresas = '';
                }

            }, function(error) {
                console.log('Erro findSemEmail: ', error);
            });
        });
    }


    angular.extend(vm, { // 
EXTEND THE PROPERTIES OF THE MAP (MARKERS, INCIAL LOCATION ..)
        center: { // 
INITIAL LOCATION.
            lat: -27.952419,
            lng: -52.211667,
            zoom: 6
        },
        defaults: { //
LAYER IS THE TYPE OF MAP TO BE USED
            tileLayer: "http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
            zoomControlPosition: 'topright',
            tileLayerOptions: {
                opacity: 0.9,
                detectRetina: true,
                reuseTiles: true,
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> | &copy <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">Funil PRÓ</a>',
            },
        }
    });
```

My problem is as follows, when the user, instead of using the system shortcuts to navigate, use the browser back arrow, the page will not reload, there is a way to make the page reload if it uses this form?

Or maybe when you access a specific route reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

> "Or maybe when you access a specific route reload the page."

Yes, you can access it by using `$routeChange` event:

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
    var urlFrom = current.$$route.originalPath; // Page you are coming from
    var urlTo   = next.$$route.originalPath;    // Page you are going to
});
```

---

*Don't forget to inject `$rootScope` and `$window` in your module.*